# Issue with ADFS with Web Api controller not redirecting to the ADFS login page

Tags: angularjs, adfs, webapi

I am facing issues with the same issue and your help will be appreciated. I have an application with AngularJS + webAPI + SQL Server, in this application I need to integrate AFDS, I have created a POC with MVC and it is working fine calling ADFS and giving me claims and all that. But when I am integrating with AngularJS + web API, this is not working.

My application structure is UI is created in AngularJS which is calling Web API, and the account controller is in Web API, where I create two login routes Login/LoginADFS, but I am not able to redirect to the ADFS login page from the controller.

Code is as below:

AccountController:

```
ADFSLogin()

{

if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

{

HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties{ RedirectUri="/"}, WsFedrationAuthencationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

}

Startup.Auth.cs:

app.UseWsFedrationAuthentication(new WsAuthenticationOptions{

Wtrealm=Startup.realm,

MetadataAddress=Startup.adfsMetaData

})
```

I can share more code details if required.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs) for some hints?

Note that this uses adal.js. You should use msal.js but there's no sample for this currently.